# How to pass an object to a separate function - Python

Tags: python, pandas, function

I’m aiming to animate a scatter plot using the df below. I’m trying to pass the `plot` and `groups` function to the `animate` function. I’m trying to return the values from each function are pass them to subsequent functions but I’m getting a`NameError` as these values aren't being registered.

The script works if I remove the `plot` and `groups` functions and pass objects to animate from the global workspace but then I have to write these out all the time. Rather than house in separate functions.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib import animation

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Time' : [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3],        
    'GroupA_X' : [3, 4, 5, 2, 5, 6, 1, 6, 7], 
    'GroupA_Y' : [2, 4, 5, 2, 5, 5, 2, 6, 5],            
    'GroupB_X' : [2, 5, 3, 2, 4, 2, 2, 3, 1],   
    'GroupB_Y' : [2, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 2, 5],                 
        })

def plot():

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.grid(False)

    xy = 0,0
    Oval = mpl.patches.Ellipse(xy, 160, 130, lw = 2, edgecolor = 'black', color = 'blue', alpha = 0.2)
    ax.add_patch(Oval)

    return fig, ax

def groups():

    plot()

    Group_A = df1[['Time','GroupA_X','GroupA_Y']]
    Group_B = df1[['Time','GroupB_X','GroupB_Y']]

    GA_X = np.array(Group_A.groupby(['Time'])['GroupA_X'].apply(list))
    GA_Y = np.array(Group_A.groupby(['Time'])['GroupA_Y'].apply(list))

    GB_X = np.array(Group_B.groupby(['Time'])['GroupB_X'].apply(list))
    GB_Y = np.array(Group_B.groupby(['Time'])['GroupB_Y'].apply(list))

    GA = ax.scatter(GA_X[0], GA_Y[0], c = ['blue'], marker = 'o', s = 10, edgecolor = 'black')
    GB = ax.scatter(GB_X[0], GB_Y[0], c = ['brown'], marker = 'o', s = 10, edgecolor = 'black')

    return GA, GB

def animate(i) :

    plot()
    groups()

    GA.set_offsets(np.c_[GA_X[0+i], GA_Y[0+i]])
    GB.set_offsets(np.c_[GB_X[0+i], GB_Y[0+i]])

plot()
groups()

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, np.arange(0,3), interval = 1000, blit = False)
```

Error Output:

> ```
> GA = ax.scatter(GA_X[0], GA_Y[0], c = ['blue'], marker = 'o', s = 10, edgecolor = 'black')
> NameError: name 'ax' is not defined
> ```

Comment: The functions return values. You should pass those values as arguments to the function.

Comment: Please provide the entire error message. Isn’t the issue that you’re throwing away the values returned by the functions?

Comment: Yep, thats the issue.

Comment: I've updated the question to reflect this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

animation draws/repeats on the global `figure`, so you need to create `subplots` in global scope. If you define `subplots` inside `plot` function, every call of `plot` will create a new `subplots`

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib import animation

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Time' : [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3],        
    'GroupA_X' : [3, 4, 5, 2, 5, 16, 21, 36, 47], 
    'GroupA_Y' : [2, 4, 5, 2, 5, 15, 22, 36, 45],            
    'GroupB_X' : [2, 5, 3, 2, 4, 12, 22, 33, 41],   
    'GroupB_Y' : [2, 4, 3, 3, 3, 14, 24, 32, 45],                 
        })

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

def plot():

#     fig, ax = plt.subplots() #declared in global scope
    ax.grid(False)

    xy = 0,0
    Oval = mpl.patches.Ellipse(xy, 160, 130, lw = 2, edgecolor = 'black', color = 'blue', alpha = 0.2)
    ax.add_patch(Oval)

#     return fig, ax #no need return since `fig, ax` are in global scope

def groups():

#   plot() #no need since this function use nothing from `plot`

    Group_A = df1[['Time','GroupA_X','GroupA_Y']]
    Group_B = df1[['Time','GroupB_X','GroupB_Y']]

    GA_X = np.array(Group_A.groupby(['Time'])['GroupA_X'].apply(list))
    GA_Y = np.array(Group_A.groupby(['Time'])['GroupA_Y'].apply(list))

    GB_X = np.array(Group_B.groupby(['Time'])['GroupB_X'].apply(list))
    GB_Y = np.array(Group_B.groupby(['Time'])['GroupB_Y'].apply(list))

    GA = ax.scatter(GA_X[0], GA_Y[0], c = ['blue'], marker = 'o', s = 10, edgecolor = 'black')
    GB = ax.scatter(GB_X[0], GB_Y[0], c = ['brown'], marker = 'o', s = 10, edgecolor = 'black')

    return GA, GB, GA_X, GA_Y, GB_X, GB_Y

def animate(i) :

#     plot()
    GA, GB, GA_X, GA_Y, GB_X, GB_Y = groups()

    GA.set_offsets(np.c_[GA_X[0+i], GA_Y[0+i]])
    GB.set_offsets(np.c_[GB_X[0+i], GB_Y[0+i]])

plot() 
# groups()

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, np.arange(0,3), interval = 1000, blit = False)
```

**Note**: I changed values in `df1` to make the values changing between each animation clearer. Codes fixing above works. I tested it. However, I don't know whether it is efficient. I basically just fix your codes to make it run.

You said animation runs fine if you declare everything in global scope. Therefore, I assume your system already had `ffmpeg` installed and you codes is able to call/find `ffmpeg.exe` to display the repreating/looping animation

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried modifying the function to pass the returned ax to a variable inside groups function as below:

```
def groups():

    _,ax = plot()
```

As the error states the name `ax` is not defined in groups function. It has to be defined by capturing the value returned from `plot()`